# SharePoint :The security validation for this page is invalid

Tags: sharepoint-designer, workflow, designer-workflow, web-services

I called a web service in SharePoint designer with **HTTP** **delete**:

```
_api/web/lists/getbytitle('title1')/items(1)/roleassignments/getbyprincipalid('1')
```

The workflow returned "**Forbidden**" response status and the ULS log :

> Exception occured in scope
>   Microsoft.SharePoint.SPRoleAssignment.DeleteObject.
>   Exception=System.Runtime.InteropServices.COMException (0x8102006D):
>   **The security validation for this page is invalid.** Click Back in your Web browser, refresh the page, and try your operation again.

Answer (score 0):

You need to send a security token (Request Digest) within your request header. It is stored in a html input with the DOM ID **__REQUESTDIGEST** on every site.
E.g. an ajax call:

```
$.ajax({
    headers: {
        "Accept": "application/json; odata=verbose",
        "content-type": "application/json;odata=verbose",
        "X-RequestDigest": $("#__REQUESTDIGEST").val()
    },
```

The lack of the token is mostly the course of the mentioned error

Comment: add it into the request header in the sharepoint designer?

Comment: name : X-RequestDigest ; type : string ; value : $("#__REQUESTDIGEST").val().   I have add this to the request header, the status is still forbidden.

Answer (score 0):

As @Dave mentioned, you need to specify the request digest to perform write operations in a REST call. But:

```
$("#__REQUESTDIGEST").val()
```

is JavaScript/jQuery code for obtaining the request digest, suitable for putting on a browser based form, but you can't use JavaScript in SharePoint designer.

In designer, you need to first call the web service `_api/contextinfo` to get the request digest, and then assign that request digest to the `X-RequestDigest` header and make the delete call.

Ref: [SharePoint Designer Call HTTP Web service with RequestDigest](https://saberghanmien.wordpress.com/2018/06/06/sharepoint-designer-call-http-web-service-with-requestdigest/)